# PTZ camera control problems

Tags: python

I need to control a PTZ camera with python code. This PTZ camera is not an IP camera and it has only USB connection to my PC. Camera has no drivers and relies on UVC as I learnt from the company of product. On manual of cam, it is written that it has pelco d, pelco c and visca protocols.

I haven't found any good lib for these protocols. I found one pyPELCO but no documentation and as I told im new to this era.
I was searching lately about pyUSB. I checked many forums but couldn't find a solution to backend problem. on some discussions, people solved this problem via installing libusb1, i did

```
pip install libusb1
```

but it didn't work for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cem/PycharmProjects/thesis/pyuvc/example.py", line 27, in <module>
    printers = usb.core.find(find_all=1, custom_match=find_class(7))
  File "C:\Users\Cem\PycharmProjects\thesis\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1263, in find
    raise NoBackendError('No backend available')
usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there any way for me to talk to the camera?
I use python 3.6 and Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]

Recently I have found a solution via using pyserial.RS485 class functions. However, now I have the problem which is when I send a PELCO D command to PTZ camera, i cannot stop this command to rotate the camera with limited angles.

```
import serial
import serial.rs485
import cv2
import time

ser = serial.Serial('com4', 9600)
ser.rs485_mode = serial.rs485.RS485Settings(rts_level_for_tx=True, rts_level_for_rx=False, loopback=False,
                                            delay_before_tx=None, delay_before_rx=None,)

print(ser.isOpen())
#PELCO D protocol commands for left right and stop action
thestring = bytearray.fromhex('FF 01 00 04 3F FF 74')
thestring2 = bytearray.fromhex('FF 01 00 02 20 3F 62')
stop = bytearray.fromhex('FF 01 00 00 00 00 01')
print(thestring)


ser.write(thestring2)
time.sleep(0.5)
ser.write(stop)
time.sleep(1)
ser.write(thestring)
time.sleep(3)
ser.write(stop)


ser.close()
```

When i use time.sleep and send PELCO D stop command afterwards, I am able to have limited angle rotation. But it is not smooth enough plus calibration of time.sleep over angles is quite hard to calculate.

Is there any solution to block RS485 communication with limited time period?

I have checked the pyserial documentation. there is a parameter for serial.Serial like 'write_timeout' but it doesn't work at all.

In a nutshell, My project includes YOLO object detection for human. So basic idea of the project is that, YOLO will detect a person and frame the person automatically with camera tracking including the pan, tilt and zoom.